# How to call html in register component using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I just researched about knockout js. I want to create directive like directive of angularJs. But I can not call html page in register component.

if anyone knows aboout this please help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

My html page is myComponent.html

```
<div><h4>Hello Word</h4></div>
```

My js file is myComponent.js

```
ko.components.register('my-component',{
  templeate: /I want call my html page/,
  viewModel: function(){
  }
});
ko.applyBindings();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you misspelled template in your sample.  Not sure if that is related or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any AMD loader such as require JS,

```
ko.components.register('my-component', {
    viewModel: { require: 'files/my-component' },
    template: { require: 'text!files/my-component.html' }
});
```

Just read about require JS kindly follow this link http://requirejs.org/